# where to put completed html & css header in Wordpress php files

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have studied for hours and do not understand how Wordpress will find and use my alternate header.

This was a good start:

```
<!--?php /* */ if(is_page(23)) { get_header('about'); } else { get_header(); } wp_head(); ?-->
```

...showing me that if on Page 23 I wanted Wordpress to insert my header instead of the default, then this would get the process started.

1 - I have created a child of a theme, and do I create (clone) a `page.php` file in the child and put this little piece of code in there?

2 - this says I create a "new" file - I think a php that will contain all the info for my alternate header.  If so, how can I get the formatting of html and css into a php?  My alternate header has text, two images, and css formatting.  What kind of file does that go into or do I create a non-php and then reference that file somehow in that php function shown above?

Thanks for anyone's help.  It seems like I am missing a few steps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to edit it to improve the formatting. You can view the help page here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You don't need to do anything with `page.php`. You need to create/clone `header.php` and call it `header-about.php`. That way if you are on the page with the id `23` it will use the `header-about.php` file. You would place this code in 'page.php` where `get_header()` currently is.

Comment: OK, thanks for a quick response.  BUT... where do I insert the code snippet to let Wordpress know I want to swap the headers?  AND... how do I get this html and css info that I am using for the second header... how do I get that into this "new" header?  If the 2nd header is a php file, how does it take on this html and css info?

Comment: Would that be the page.php of the parent, or should I create one of those for the child, too?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give the [Theme Development & Standards](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Development_Standards) documentation and the [Child Themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) documentation a thorough review. There's an enormous amount of information to digest though, so I understand how daunting it can be.

Regarding the "How WordPress finds and uses your alternate header" - it's just a native part of the [`get_header()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) function. If you leave it empty or pass it an invalid value, it loads the default `header.php` file. If you pass it the string `'about'` it will try and load `header-about.php` and fall back to `header.php` if it can't find it.

Also note that the header in question is different than [`wp_head()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) the main use for which is to load scripts or data into the `<head>` tag, which should come before your `<header>` or `<div id="header">` (menu/logo, etc.) type output.

If you're using a child theme, cloning `page.php` from the parent theme will use the child theme's version instead, and you can safely make modifications to it there. Same with `header.php`, `header-about.php`, or any other files. You should only need to clone `page.php` from the parent if that's where `get_header()` is called (this can vary depending on how the parent theme was created and structured)

Any CSS used to format the alternate header should still be placed inside your `style.css` (or `style-about.css` similar) file and [Properly Enqueued](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#enqueuing-scripts-and-styles) using the `wp_enqueue_style` function on the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook.

All the structural code (PHP/HTML) for your `about` header should be placed into `header-about.php` which should probably start out as a copy of `header.php` if there's any structural functions or code if there's anything else the rest of the theme/site layout relies on in there.

Here's a few examples of how your files may look:

## child-theme/page.php

```
<?php
    // Anything early-on in the parent theme's `page.php`

    // Load `about` on page 23, otherwise default
    // Ternary operatory for brevity
    get_header( is_page(23) ? 'about' : null );

    // Rest of `page.php`
?>
```

## child-theme/functions.php

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so60570540_enqueue_assets' );
    function so60570540_enqueue_assets(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0' );

        if( is_page( 23 ) ){
            wp_enqueue_style( 'child-about', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style-about.css', array('child-style'), '1.0' );            
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Great, thorough answer.  Thanks!  I will follow it piece-by-piece and see where I come out.